# How does Google Webmaster tools deal with subdomains

Tags: google-search-console, subdomain

My site is set up so the main site is `http://example.com` and report pages are on Amazon S3 at `http://reports.example.com`.

There are obviously links between the two sites, I assumed that adding  `http://example.com` to Webmaster Tools would also include `http://reports.example.com` but it doesn't. I have added that separately.

But is there way to tell Webmaster Tools they are part of the same website. And if I want to index all the pages on `http://reports.example.com` do I need an `index.html` file (or similar) which has hyperlinks to the pages as `http://reports.example.com/index.html` or could the files still be indexed if the listing file resided on `http://example.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every domain (in this case a subdomain) must has its own sitemap and its own robots.txt so you can teach to the crawlers (not only google even Yandex, Yahoo, Bing... ). The thing is that You can't mix urls from one sitemap inside the other .... so sitemap from subdomain only must contain urls from this subdomain not the main domain and same applies for domain sitemap as can't contains in its sitemap urls from the subdomain.

To summarize please create robots.txt and sitemap.xml.gz for every domain and subdomain as it's not enough to have a index.html

You can find very good resources searching for robots.txt and sitemap in Google